# How do I fix user registration on my new Laravel project?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, registration

I created a new Laravel project. I used the standard `php artisan make:auth` 
and that generated the required files and connections. I created the table in phpMyAdmin and connected the two in the *.env* file. I checked connections and migrations and all works well.

The problem is that when I want to create a new user and enter all the register data, the fields `first_name` and `last_name` apparently can not be read and I get an error saying *"The first name field is required."* Same for last name. No error on password or email.

First, here's the RegisterController:

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'first_name' => 'required|string|max:20',
        'last_name' => 'required|string|max:30',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);
}

protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
        'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

register.blade.php:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{   route('register') }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}

    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('first_name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
        <label for="first_name" class="col-md-4 control-label">First Name</label>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="first_name" type="text" class="form-control" first_name="first_name" value="{{ old('first_name') }}" required autofocus>

            @if ($errors->has('first_name'))
                <span class="help-block">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('first_name') }}</strong>
                </span>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('last_name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
        <label for="last_name" class="col-md-4 control-label">Last Name</label>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="last_name" type="text" class="form-control" last_name="last_name" value="{{ old('last_name') }}" required autofocus>

            @if ($errors->has('last_name'))
                <span class="help-block">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('last_name') }}</strong>
                </span>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>
```

And migrations:

```
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('first_name', 20);
            $table->string('last_name', 30);
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password', 30);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

I checked forums and the Laravel documentation but couldn't find a mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
<input id="first_name" type="text" class="form-control" first_name="first_name" value="{{ old('first_name') }}" required autofocus>
```

here instead of `name="first_name"`, `first_name="first_name"` is there. Make it proper and try again. Same for `last_name="last_name"` also.

**Explanation:**

On the server side, element value is fetched using the `name` attribute of element. But in your case `name` attribute is missing which causes the validation to fails and it is showing **The first name field is required** and same for `last_name`